# Using SaaS along with PaaS

Tags: cloud, saas, paas

I've read some information on the SaaS/PaaS/IaaS and I'm thinking of this:

if I offered a SaaS application, could my customer develop and deploy his own application using PaaS which would interact with my SaaS-application using some API?
Or am I getting the idea of cloud services wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right PAAS provides development, testing, and deployment environment like framework , hosting space etc. So developer can develop applications quick, simple, and in cost-effective  manner and Developer can also  use your SAAS api to integrate your services in its product.

For example `google app engine` is PAAS and you `GMail` service is SAAS. So using `google app engine` you can develop and deploy your own app and in which you can give [mail service](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) by integrating `GMail` api.